# Inserting image file to oracle database inserts null value

Tags: java, oracle, jsp

I am trying to insert a image into oracle database as a BLOB, I am using the jsp file to upload the required image. After the form is submitted a 'UploadServlet' is called. 
Following is the code of the servlet that inserts the image to the table.
But when I see the table values it just shows 'NULL' in column of table.
Please review my code and advice where I am wrong . Thank you

The UploadExample.jsp

```
<body>
<form action="UploadServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <center>
    <label id="l_file" for="upload">[File Upload]</label>
    <input type="file" placeholder="Upload file" name="uploadFile"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
    </center>
</form>
```

UploadServlet.java

```
@WebServlet("/UploadServlet")
@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize=16177215)
public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    //check request content type
    System.out.println("Content type of request is " +  request.getContentType());

    Connection currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();

    InputStream inputStream = null; // input stream of the upload file

    Part filePart = request.getPart("uploadFile");
      if (filePart != null) {
            // prints out some information for debugging
            System.out.println(filePart.getName());
            System.out.println(filePart.getSize());
            System.out.println(filePart.getContentType());

            // obtains input stream of the upload file
            inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
        }

     String sql = "insert into photo values(?)";

     try {
            PreparedStatement ps = currentCon.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setBlob(1, inputStream);
            int row = ps.executeUpdate();
            if(row>0)
            {
                System.out.println("The photo has been uploaded successfully");
            }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of `setBlob`

```
ps.setBinaryStream(1, inputStream, inputStream.available());
```